# Pass parameter to a webservice using ksoap2?

Tags: java, android, ksoap

I have a simple web service method with a parameter like follows

```
public String fetchOrderInfo(int g){
...
```

}

I want to pass a value to int g from an Android program using ksoap2. I have used some thing like this but this doesn't work

```
...
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);  
    PropertyInfo oId = new PropertyInfo();
    oId.flags=3;
    oId.type=PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
    request.addProperty(oId,3);
...
```

How can I pass a value to int g ?? (Severer is Tomcat7)
 Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("g", 3);
...
```